# How to travel from Vienna airport to Győr

Tags: airport-transfer, hungary, vienna, vie

I need a fast and reliable ride from Vienna airport to Győr downtown on a specific day at a specific time (leaving about 12:30 on a Wednesday). I arrive by plane to VIE. What options do I have?

- By car it takes abut 110 minutes, so if I take a taxi, I arrive to Győr at 14:20. But a taxi is probably too expensive.
- There are scheduled trains, e.g. at 13:33 from Vienna airport, change at
  Wien Hauptbahnhof, arriving to Győr at 15:17. This is my baseline. I'm looking for options which arrive to Győr earlier than 15:17. (But according to oebb.at, this particular train is expected to be late.)
- oszkar.com doesn't list any cars for that time period, and I'm not willing to wait until 17:00, when the first listed car arrives to Vienna airport.
- blablacar.com doesn't list any cars at all.
- I know about the microbus service http://www.aerobus.hu/en/gyor-vienna-airport-transfer, of reasonable price.
- Does hitchhiking work from Vienna airport? Do I get a reasonable chance to get taken quickly? Where in the airport should I show up?

Are the any other options I've missed?

Comment: What day of the week?

Comment: The day of the week is Wednesday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although VIE Airport is between Vienna and the Hungarian border, it's not on the main East-West rail line (there are plans to route some long distance trains here in the future once a connecting spur is built). The airport is also not well connected to the main Austria-Hungary rail line by other public transit, hence it's generally faster to backtrack through Vienna when travelling by train.

You do have a few options:

- A scheduled bus may be a good option. If you can swing it, [Orangeways](http://orangeways.com) has a bus at 11:55 arriving on the outskirts of Gyor at 13:00. Over at [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-vienna-gyor/r/u2edk8-u2kx32) we list some other bus options. You can filter to departing the airport after you search. For the test date I looked at, most have a transfer in Bratislava and they didn't get you there faster than the train, but schedules vary depend on the actual travel date and change frequently, so they can be worth checking.
- By train, instead of backtracking to Vienna you could take a cab or the [regional bus 273](https://www.postbus.at/de/Fahrplanauskunft/Fahrplandownload/index.jsp?search=true&land=BURGENLAND&fahrplanabfrage=) straight from VIE Airport to Bruck/Leitha and catch the regional train to Gyor. There's a train departing Bruck/Leitha at 12:48 arriving 14:10 - by cab it's a 20 minute drive from the airport. By transit there's a bus leaving 12:52 arriving at Bruck/Leitha at 13:30, onward by train at 14:48 arriving 16:10.
- Hitchhiking can be doable though it may take time. You could specifically approach people at the airport gas station or supermarket (both located at 48.124841, 16.562770 - which you can walk to from the terminal) who have an Hungarian licence plate.

Answer (score 2):

[DB Bahn](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?ld=15082&protocol=https:&seqnr=8&ident=lf.0642982.1500551486&rt=1&OK#focus) lists a railjet Train from the airport 13:33 to Wien Hbf. Connecting to a railet bound for Budapest there, you'll arrive in Györ at 15:17.

If wanting to get there quicker, Aerobus seems to be the only Option at that time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I had these options already in the question.

Answer (score 2):

oszkar.com tends to get new cars listed as the actual date comes closer. (Personally I don't like to do these last minute reservations, but if you're adventurous enough it may be worth to check them again a day before your arrival.)